# Slow page load times with paypal express checkout integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, paypal, nopcommerce

I'm looking into a website which has slow loading times.
Sometimes it takes 15 seconds or more before the page starts to paint to the screen.
When I analyze the website using the chrome dev tools I see whats in the following image :
[image]

This appears before the waterfall starts.
Furthermore when I pause the network recording in dev tools and hover my mouse over the logger name it shows a url to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/logger

Does anyone know about this issue at all.
Waiting 15 or more seconds for the page to start rendering is way to long.

I have done some research but can't find anything about this problem.
I didn't build the website either so I'm still trying to gather more information about how paypal has been integrated.
I know it's using express checkout.
As far as I can tell, the logger that shows in dev tools is some kind of ajax request which is the first thing that happens when the browser refresh button is pressed.

Cheers

Comment: I know it's an old post, but were you able to find a fix or an improvement for this? I have the same issue, it's always loading 10-20 seconds just to load the PayPal checkout page. Tried everything to get it to a more reasonable waiting time, but nothing seems to work.